# Excel VBA macro failing to save workbook on coworker's computer, but fine on mine

Tags: excel, vba, virtual-machine, save-as

I'm encountering an issue trying to get some macros and VBA scripts working on a new coworker's computer.  I've been using the same code for years on my machine and several others without issue, but when my new analyst tries to run it, it throws an error stating it couldn't save the file.  He can manually save the file without issue, but running the script throws the error.  The really weird part is that it lists the file path, but replaces the filename with a seemingly random hex byte.

On another file, if he opens it, closes with or without saving, then I open the file and try to save it using a macro, it fails saying "cannot access file...".  If I copy and paste the file, open and run the macro again, it saves over the offending file no problem.

We've checked permissions and settings and haven't found anything that was different between the two systems.  We're both on VMs.  His hardware allowance is less than mine but otherwise they're both IT-managed and identical.  I'm at my wits' end...  Any advice on what may be the source of my grief would be helpful, even if not a solution.

Comment: Posting relevant code always helps with suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I'd check before trying to step through debugger mode.

1. Coworker does not have write access to the directory (I think you said you checked already)
2. The new users' Trust Center Settings are not correct

   - File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings... > Macro Settings > Ensure the box is checked to trust the VBA model and that macros are not disabled
3. The new user does not have the same libraries referenced.

   - Alt + F11 > Tools > References... > Check if coworkers' libs match yours
4. Is he using a new/different version of Excel that you? A lot of older code got bojangled when Office 365 hit the scene.

After checking settings, I would ask the following:

- What error is thrown when coworker attempts to run the macro?
- When does the error get thrown? It could be that you have code that is attempting to edit the file (or has another file stuck in an edit) at the same time you're trying to save it.
- I would see why the file name is getting corrupted. It sounds like coworkers' machine is looking to a bit of memory or memory address that is somehow getting forgotten. Like the code is referencing a variable that is out of scope.
- User Access Control has been enabled on his VM that is somehow preventing him from saving the file correctly.
- Your code does not properly Quit the Excel application, so its still running in the background on coworkers' machine. Have them open/close without saving a file and check Task Manager to see if Excel is still up to confirm